# Listings rule breaking into pieces when using xleftmargin=3pt,xrightmargin=3pt

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I'm using the below coding in a Tex file and when I view the DVI output the frame rule for listings gets breakdown (please look into the screenshot below)

Could some one help me in solving this issue?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}

\overfullrule=12pt

\definecolor{dkgreen}{cmyk}{0.81,0.48,0.95,0.59}%
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0.69,0.63,0.62,0.59}%
\definecolor{mauve}{cmyk}{0.84,1,0.27,0.39}%


\makeatletter
\def\@viiihpt{8.5}

\newcommand\codesize{\@setfontsize\codesize\@viiihpt{10}}

\lstset{
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\codesize,
   backgroundcolor=\color{white},
   showspaces=false,
   showstringspaces=false,
   frame=single,xleftmargin=3pt,xrightmargin=3pt,
   rulecolor=\color{black},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   stringstyle=\color{mauve}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Book title}

\lstinputlisting[float=b,language=Python,
   caption=Creating a Tk Root Widget (Python Coding),
   label=P04-Tk.py] {P04-Tk.py}

\end{document}
```

Below is the coding used in `P04-Tk.py`

```
from tkinter import *                                 # import Tkinter module

root = Tk()                                           # create Tk root widget

root.mainloop()                                    # enter Tkinter event loop
```

**edit:** [barbara beeton]

this also happens when the files are processed with pdflatex, and only when the
comments are moved to a new line.  here are the results with the original code, and with the `.py` file modified to shorten the lines so all of them remain on a single line in the output:

[image]

[image]

is this a bug, or is there a known solution other than avoiding (or breaking) long lines?

Comment: Please use an `lstlisting` environment instead of `\lstinputlisting`, or edit your question to add the code for `P04-Tk.py`.

Comment: The code is running well, but you have to offer `P04-Tk.py` file. I tried your code with some files.

Comment: Like @ferahfeza, I can't reproduce the bug. Try updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: the problem happens only when a comment is moved to a new line by the package.  it appears that the left margin is not inserted at the line break, but the right margin is instead "adjusted" by that amount, so the frame is broken on both sides.  i'm not sufficiently familiar with the package to dig into its innards, or have time to study the documentation; perhaps someone who is more familiar can say whether it's a bug, or there is a known mechanism for fixing the problem.  (a manual approach could be to shorten the gap so no lines need to be broken.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use option `breaklines`

```
\lstinputlisting[float=b,language=Python,breaklines,
   caption=Creating a Tk Root Widget (Python Coding),
   label=P04-Tk.py] {P04-Tk.py}
```

[image]